# Multidimensional array in Java with for function - Schildt

Tags: java, arrays

This multidimensional array of displayed in Schildt' book, 9th edition.
I do not understand how the output, except for the `0, 1, 2, 3, 4`.
Can you explain how the other `for loop` works?
I understand that 4 and 5 are the number of rows and columns, but I do not comprehend the values: `15, 16, 17, 18, 19`.

```
class TwoDArray {  
  public static void main(String args[]) {  
    int twoD[][]= new int[4][5];  
    int i, j, k = 0;  
    for(i=0; i<4; i++)  
      for(j=0; j<5; j++) {  
        twoD[i][j] = k;  
        k++;  
    }  
    for(i=0; i<4; i++) {  
      for(j=0; j<5; j++) 
        System.out.print(twoD[i][j] + " ");  
      System.out.println();  
    }  
}
```

}

This program generates the following output:

```
 0 1 2 3 4  
 5 6 7 8 9  
 10 11 12 13 14  
 15 16 17 18 19
```

Comment: Use a debugger to step through the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loops are executed and k is incremented for total 4*5 = 20 times. Here is how the program is executed

```
for(i=0; i<4; i++)  // Run outer loop 4 times
  for(j=0; j<5; j++) {  // For every outer loop iteration, run inner loop 5 times
    twoD[i][j] = k;  
    k++;  // for every inner loop iteration, increment k by 1
}
```